# How do I view and clear up untrusted certificates in a browser?

Tags: firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using Firefox. For untrusted certificates, one may choose to accept. I want to know where to view those certificates and then how to clear them. I try clean the cache, but after that when I reload the same page (via HTTPS) it does not ask me to accept certificate. So it still remains in the browser somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox 20 or higher, you can look in Tools → Options → Advanced → Certificates → View Certificates, which lists all certificates used in Firefox. You can then delete the ones you want to remove.

Comment: I have Firefox 24.0, but no Tools\Options.

Comment: Try Options -> Options. The exceptions will be in the Server tab (in View Certificates).

Comment: OK, it is located under Edit->Preferences->Advanced... and it seems to work. Except that after I delete the certificate, I cannot reinstall it (the "Confirm Security Exception" button becomes gray).

Comment: @user180574. As a general rule, Tools → Options on Windows is Edit → Preferences on Linux. This applies to many programs, not just Firefox.